# Python continue and break usage

Tags: python, dictionary, continue

I need to solve the following problem and I assume I have to use `continue` and `break` logic.

- I have to create an empty `to do list` and iterate over the dictionary of `tasks`. I need to add tasks that contain the substring `"organize"` and once the length of the `to do list` reaches 2 tasks I break the loop. *

```
tasks = {
    0 : ['Reorganize the cabinet'],
    1 : ['Give the dog a bath', 'Create a twitter thread'],
    2 : ['Learn python dictionary'],
    3 : ['Take a walk'], 
    4 : ['Go grocery shopping'], 
    5 : ['Update Facebook'],
    6 : ['Respond to emails'],
    7 : ['Walk the dog']
}
```

I could solve the second part of adding the tasks that contain the substring "organize"  and could iterate through the length of tasks to filter tasks that are not more than 2. Yet, I can't find the way how to combine two conditions into one.

Comment: `if len(todo_list) == 2: break` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Can you show what the expected result is supposed to be? Your dictionary elements are lists. Do you want the whole list if either if the elements contains `organize`, or just the individual strings that match? E.g. if one of the tasks were `['organize dog food', 'feed dog']` should the result contain that whole list or just `organize dog food`? And would that count as 1 task or 2?

Answer (score 2):

Put an `if` statement in the loop that checks the length of the to do list, and breaks out of the loop when it reaches 2.

```
todo_list = []
for task in tasks.values():
    if any('organize' in item for item in task):
        todo_list.append(task)
    if len(todo_list) == 2:
        break
```

Comment: this results in empty list. check your code

Comment: I just noticed that the original dictionary contains lists, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

does this do the job:

```
to_do_list = []
for value in tasks.values():
    to_do_list.append([val for val in value if 'organize' in val])
    if len(to_do_list) == 2:
        break
```

If you want a flattened list of items, replace `to_do_list.append` with `to_do_list.extend`

Comment: Why do you need `key`? You never use it.

Comment: @Barmar is my answer correct ?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, you are right. We don't need `keys`, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: The question isn't very clear about how the separate strings in each task are supposed to be handled. I've posted a comment above asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

```
to_do_list = []

for task in tasks.values():
    for i in task :
        if 'organize' in i:
            to_do_list.append(i)
    if len(to_do_list) == 2:
        break
```